# Run a Script within Autocad from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autocad-scripts

I have an excel workbook that creates an runs several calculations to create a new sheet.

From this new sheet it plots an array of commands for Autocad once it's exported to an AutoCAD script.

The script is saved to a predifined location ("C:\Autocad\Drawing To Drop In****.SCR"), what im try to achieve is from within Excel can it automate the manual dropping of the script into the AuutoCAD.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to start AutoCAD and call a script from a Vbnet app using WinForms.
It should be possible to do something similar with VBA.

**To write a Vba app in AutoCAD, type 'vbaman' on the AutoCAD command line.**

Here's a repo with a sample Vbnet app that can launch AutoCAD and call a script.
There probably is away to launch this Vbnet app directly from excel I would imagine.

https://github.com/cadwiki/cadwiki-free-solutions

Comment: mark as a solution if this helped. Thanks